# Ubuntu Saucy: What is the default console tool for parsing XML?

Tags: apt, 13.10, package-management, xml

I used `xmllint` package for parsing `xml` files. Also, I know, that we can use `xml2`, `xmlstarlet` too.

But I do not see those packages in `Ubuntu Saucy`.

Does `Saucy` contain any default `xml` parsers?

I need parse xml file one time and I do no want install addition packages for this.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of a "default", but **xmllint** is included with the **libxml2-utils** package.

```
apt-get install libxml2-utils
```

Comment: is this still the preferred way to install `xmllint` itself?

Comment: AFAIK, it's the _only_ package that includes it. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=xmllint